# How to put a range.formula into a loop in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

first of all I would like to apologize as I am not a programmer, but I am now forced to act as in order to successfully complete a task assigned to me.
I am building an excel dashboard and I needed to use some VBA programming. All good so far whit the hints I have got from you, but currently I am stuck in a loop...:))

I am trying to write a specific formula, always the same in a range of cells calculated by the software. Actually in the loop below everything works:

```
For i = 1 To LastCYMonth_RNG.Rows.count
    LastCYMonth_RNG.Cells(i, 1) = Application.Sum(YTDCYAll_RNG.Rows(i)) - Application.Sum(TotalCYMonth_RNG.Rows(i)) - Application.Sum(MTDCYMonth_RNG.Rows(i))
 Next i
```

What I can not manage to do is instead of making a Sum I want to write a formula in each cell of the range.....like

`Range("BX11:BX13").Formula = "=SUM(C2:D2)"` where `"BX11:BX13"` must be replaced by the calculated range `LastCYMonth_RNG` in a programmatic manner......no clue about the syntax or mistake a might make.

Thanks a lot.

Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small working sample which should show you how to go about it:

```
Sub test()
   Dim LastCYMonth_RNG As Range
    Set LastCYMonth_RNG = Range("B2:c4")

    LastCYMonth_RNG.Formula = "=sum(a1:a5)"
End Sub
```

1) make sure your `LastCYMonth_RNG` variable is actually declared as a data type named `RANGE`.

2) Set your range to whatever you need (in my test : `B2:C4`, in your sample code, `BX11:BX13` .. or whatever else you calculated. 
 If you cannot calculate `BX11:BX13`, but rather end up with: `( row 11, col 76 )` : `( row 13, col 76 )`, you can use the worksheet function `ADDRESS` to build it. [edit] correction - just use `CELLS`, not `ADDRESS` ... [/edit]

3) Once you have that, you can just stuff it into your Formula call.

Comment: Hi Ditto, many taking the time. It worked fine for me and I fixed my issue. I would like just to highlight something strange that happened to me as inexperienced user.

Comment: Hi Ditto, many taking the time. It worked fine for me and I fixed my issue. I would like just to highlight something strange that happened to me as inexperienced user. By addending the real formula to the command I was running into a 1004 Error and It cost me an headache trying to understand. The issue was in the separator I have used in the formula inside the "" that was not right for VBA but right for Excel......in other words to set the formula to =IF($AF$5=0;0;IF($AF$5>=6;$DR11;0)) I had to use "," instead of ";"....Thnka once again. Stefano

Comment: @stefano: Yeah, I've always used comas "," ... only started seeing semi-colons ";" on this site .. :)  Oh well. Remember to mark the question answered if my answer helped you ...  Cheers.